# Features installed with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have access to a VM that has SQL Server running. I wanted to find out what features were installed at set up.

I don't have admin access and was wondering if there was a configuration table I could query?

I'm most used to oracle and I have lots more experience with AWS, docker, RDS and Glue/Athena. Why the client would choose this out dated tech is beyond me.

Comment: What in particular are you looking for?  If you don't have admin access, you might not be able to examine the server configuration by any means.  For a non-admin using a SQL Server in a VM is really no different than using SQL Server in RDS.

Comment: I just wanted to know what features were installed at installation time. In oracle this was so much easier - even with out admin access. I was hoping for a sqlserver equivalent to : select
   name c1,
   detected_usages c2,
   first_usage_date c3,
   currently_used c4
from
   dba_feature_usage_statistics
where
   first_usage_date is not null

Answer (score 2):

> I was hoping for a sqlserver equivalent to : `select name c1, detected_usages c2, first_usage_date c3, currently_used c4 from dba_feature_usage_statistics . . .`

Unlike Oracle, SQL Server doesn't have a bunch of optional features in the RDBMS that cost extra.

Feature availability varies somewhat by [edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2016), which a non-admin can query with

```
select @@version
```

But as of SQL Server 2016 SP1 almost all the features that a developer would care about are available in every edition.  Things like advanced compression, partitioning, memory-optimized tables, native-compiled procedures, columnar storage,  row-level security, and change data capture were reserved for Enterprise Edition in older versions.  But not any longer.

Comment: WHAt about the features installed at set up such as full text search etc ?

Comment: That one you can check with `select FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')`  And some features require admin consent to use, like .NET Stored Procedures.

Comment: Can I check any others like poly base etc ? Thank you for your help - is there a resource for this ?

Comment: Polybase state is visible in server configuration `exec sp_configure 'polybase enabled'`

Comment: You have been so helpful - thank you so much. Just to check then, with out access to the configuration manager - there isn’t a convenient place where all the drop down features at installation can be found ?

Comment: Right.  The configuration manager and/or the installer are the normal place to manage this.  And there's not a single query that will output everything.